# how to place control in a td

Tags: asp.net, html-table

I try to set two control in a td.
1. use a panel. as follow.

```
  <td style="display: inline;">
            <asp:Panel ID="pContainer" runat="server" Wrap="false">
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtxtBookingID" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBookingID"
                    runat="server" ControlToValidate="rtxtBookingID" ErrorMessage="|Booking ID"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   
                <telerik:RadButton ID="rbtnOpen" runat="server" Text="Browse" OnClientClicked="openViewWindow()"/> 
            </asp:Panel>

        </td>
```

how to solve the problem.
if I use two td to place the two control . but the first control in the td will gernerate a div. so the two control distance is far?

Comment: Why do you need to place a panel? td and div don't play well together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it works and you get ok behaviour you are fine and for layout issues you should use css. The way you place the controls on the page also depends on overall page design and structure, keep in mind that usage of tables to control layout is not promoted anymore and you should use divs and css whenever possible... again depending on whole page design of course.